# Map One Drive Documents/Folders to MS CRM Documents

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm-2013, onedrive

We have an Office365 subscription with Sharepoint, CRM, One Drive etc.

Problem is that my company wants to map documents in OneDrive folder to MS-CRM(2013) Document.

Now I have done a Sharepoint Document Integration with CRM which is provided out of the box by MS.
But I dont have a clue as to how do we integrate one drive folder/document to Sharepoint Document.

1. Can it be done out of the box?
2. Can it be done through Sharepoint?
3. Do we have to write some kind of code to do this?

Thanks in advance for any tips, articles, blogs anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to integrate through Onedrive SDK. Have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631819.aspx

You can find various C# code sample on net for that.

I have not done by myself with CRM. However, I have done very similar thing with Classic NAV using .NET COM integration.

Here is the sample code that you may like to see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn631823.aspx